# Amchart Export button and menu do not disappear after click

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using AmCharts' export plugin and I noticed that when I click on the export button or export drop down menus, it stays active and does not get hidden.  The active class also does not change after clicking next menu.

You can see this in my attached screenshot where I clicked both "Download as" and "Save as".

[image]

```
  'export': {
                        'enabled': true,
                        'divId': 'amchart-export-wrapper',
                        // 'menu': ['JPG', 'PNG','PDF','SVG'],
                        'libs': {
                            'path': '../bower_components/amcharts-src/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/'
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: please post relevant code.

Comment: I have added the code I used for export @Pengyy. I am saying that this issue occurs in amchart itself. Please find the sample link.
[ https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/selectively-removing-export-formats-from-default-export-menu ]

Comment: This is a bug. Will let you know when it's fixed. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Fixed in 1.4.66 https://github.com/amcharts/export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed that issue using a directive

```
<span id="amchart-export-wrapper" export-menu-class></span>

'export': {
                    'enabled': true,
                    'divId': 'amchart-export-wrapper',
                    // 'menu': ['JPG', 'PNG','PDF','SVG'],
                    'libs': {
                        'path': '../bower_components/amcharts-src/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/'
                    }
                }
```

exportMenuDirective:

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('exportMenuClass',
['$document',
function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      function removeActiveClass() {
        $element.find('.export-main.active').removeClass('active');
        $element.find('.export-main li.active').removeClass('active');
      }
      $document.on('click', function() {
        removeActiveClass();
      });
      $element.on('click', '.export-main,.export-main li', function(event) {            
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        removeActiveClass();
        angular.element(event.currentTarget).addClass('active');
      });
      $element.bind('mouseleave', function() {
        removeActiveClass();
      });
    },
  };
}]
);
```

Comment: Or, you can update Export plugin (no need to do anything if you are using CDN version) to the latest version. It fixes the issue.